# Code that is able to search for a string in a text recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I have a code which satisfies the question above. However, I am personally curious on how to recode it such that if the text did not have a space and is given as `"LoveIsWar"`, the code will still return true if the string is `"War"`.

However, I thought of doing a check for letter by letter but I am unsure how to do it. Would really appreciate if I could get guidance on this!

```
def find(text, substring):
    if(len(text) <= 0):
        return None
    elif(text[0] == substring):
        return substring
    else:
        return find(text[1:], substring)


def is_string_there(text, string):
    if find(text.split(), string):
        return True
    else: return False

print(is_string_there("love is war","war"))
print(is_string_there("love is war","warfalse"))
```

This is the edited code that satisfies everything I want. Being able to check for the string if the text has spaces or not even if the string has capital letters in it.

```
def find(text, substring):
    if(len(text) <= 0):
        return None
    elif(text[0:len(substring)] == substring):
        return substring
    else:
        return find(text[1:], substring)


def is_string_there(text, string):
    if find(text.lower(), string.lower()):
        return True
    else: return False

print(is_string_there("love is war","war"))
print(is_string_there("love is war","warfalse"))
```

Comment: So you want to handle both the cases in same code ? String with spaces and without spaces ?

Comment: yes, I dont know if its possible but im still trying right now haha

Comment: I posted an answer that would be able to handle both the cases. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question. Given the constraint of a *recursive* function, in layman's terms, what you want to achieve is a sliding-window search on a string.

That is to say, that when you pass your 'text' into the find function, you do not pass it as an array, you pass the text itself.

The 'find' function then doesn't iterate through the elements in the 'array', but through the letters in the string, discarding them one by one. Hence, your "window" - or your view on the string, slides across it until you finish.

All you really need to modify is:

`text[0] == substring`

Should check if the `text[0:length_of_substring]` matches the substring. Remember, we have much the same operations on strings as we do on arrays!

If it does not, move 1 character along (much like you do in your array-based search).

For your interest, these kinds of problems can be solved very efficiently using algorithms such as [Rabin Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)

A small optimisation you could make is *breaking* out of your search when you have fewer characters left in your "text" than there are in your substring.

Hope that helps!

Comment: If you get stuck, add a comment here and I'll be happy to help. I want you to learn, so I didn't give you the code up front, but I can help you get there :)

Comment: Oh wait! i managed to do it haha but I still need you to check to see if what I did was what you meant. Ill, put it above.

Comment: That's great @Samuel, well done.

You can make your program resilient against case changes for lower and upper case by simply either upcasing both your inputs, or lowercasing both of them before you pass them into the "find" function.

Comment: `text[0:len(substring)]` is a "slice" operation on a string. In much the same way you can "slice" out elements of an array, so too, can you slice out letters in a string. Thus, in "abcde", we can slice out "abcd" if we so pleased, using the `[n:m]` syntax. This allows us to *iteratively search strings*.
I'm glad this answer helped you, please don't forget to accept/upvote it if you feel like it catered to your problem effectively :)

Comment: thank you, I understand what you mean now! I have upvoted but since im still a new member, it does not show for you haha.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something but why aren't you using the `in` keyword?

```py
>>>"War" in "Love is War"
true
>>>"War" in "LoveIsWar"
true
>>>"Warfalse" in "Love is War"
false
```

Comment: I did not use the "in" keyword as I want it to be a recursive function. By using in, I thought that it would not be a recursive function anymore but please correct me if im wrong!

Comment: I'm not sure how ```in``` is implemented but why do you want it to be recursive?

Comment: I just started learning recursion so im challenging myself to do recursion for this question but its so hard for me :')

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `in` to figure out if a substring is present in a given string or not.

Something like this :

```
myString1 = "Love Is War"
myString2 = "LoveIsWar"

print("War" in myString1)

print("War" in myString2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer as it answers both cases of whether there is a space or not. But by doing this, I wasnt sure if my code still recursive. That was what made this so difficult for me because I would not need to call my function again by using in.

Comment: I did not understand the last line. Can you please explain why would you need to cll function again ?

Comment: I am doing a recursive function so I have to call the function again for it to be recursive

Answer (score 0):

you do know you can check for substrings in python using the `in` operator?

```py
if "war".lower() in "LoveIsWar".lower():
    return True
```

lower is used to match case insensitive

if you do need it to be a recursive function i suggest takign a look at this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-function-to-do-substring-search/

Comment: thank you! I was actually using that as a reference but I want to figure out how to do it without text and pat index. I totally forgot about .lower() though, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
def finder(s, x, y):
    if len(x) == 0:
        return True
    elif len(s) < len(x):
        return False
    elif s[0] == x[0]:
        return finder(s[1:], x[1:], y)
    else:
        return finder(s[1:], y, y)
print(finder("1011101110", "111", "111"))
```

Comment: Care to explain?